# Installing a node module from a gobally installed version

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have an interesting question. let us say that I'm going on a holiday where I don't have access to the internet. I happen to bring my laptop with me so that I can write some code. Me being an idiot or smart depending on perspective, I usually install my node modules using the global flag. I suspect that this adds the module locally.

My Question.

Is it possible to **npm install** a module locally installed into a new project without having access to the internet?

if so, what command does one run?

Answer (score 0):

This is another way.

You will need to use the npm install command with the **--offline** flag, like this:

```
npm install --offline \<nameOfModule>
```